# About $n$-th differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

For real function we can use MVT to show that if it is $n$-th differentiable at a point $x_0$ then it can be estimate by an degree $n$ polynomial with error term of $o((x-x_0)^n)$.
Similarly, if we are given an complex function that is $n$-th (complex) differentiable on a point $z_0$ (and not sure about its analycity), then is it true that it can be estimate by an degree $n$ polynomial with error term of $o((z-z_0)^n)$?
In other word, is it true that the function is of such form?
$c_0+c_1(z-z_0)+...+c_n(z-z_0)^n+e(z-z_0)$ where $e\in o(z^n)$

Comment: What do you mean by differentiable? Differentiable as a function of two real variables? Or $\mathbb C$ differentiable ?

Comment: In the real case, using MVT we can prove a stronger statement: $\text{error}=O((x-x_0)^{n+1})$ (this form is called Lagrange's form, while the one you used is Peano's form)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net It's complex differentiable. I've edit my question.

Comment: @gabrielecassese I can see that it is true for the real case, but I'm wondering if this is also true for a complex function.

Comment: Oops, I thought Lagrange's form would require $n+1$-th differentiable.

Comment: @TaylorHuang It depends in which form do you give to MVT. In its classical forms, i.e.: $f(z+h)-f(z_0)=f'(z)h$, then you can easily give a counterexample considering: $f=e^{ix}\rightarrow f(2\pi)-f(0)=0\neq f'(z)(2\pi-0)$
About Lagrange's form: it does not require $f\in C^{n+1}(x_0)$, but it does require the function to be $n$ differentiable in a open neighborough of $x_0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=1$, the result is true by definition of $\mathbb C$-differentiability.

And for $n \ge 2$, the hypothesis of $f$ being $n$ times $\mathbb C$-differentiable at $z_0$ implies by definition that $f$ is $n-1$ times $\mathbb C$-differentiable in a neighborhood of $z_0$. Hence $f$ is holomorphic around $z_0$. Therefore $f$ can be written as a power series. And it can be approximated with a polynomial to any order.

Comment: I think you might miss cases that $f$ is complex differentiable only at some boundary point. Because we are only given $f$ differentiable at some point rather then in its neighbor or some domain.

Comment: @TaylorHuang I update my answer.